# Constraints altering View visibility

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Why does `void ConstraintSet.applyToInternal(ConstraintLayout constraintLayout);` changes the `View` visibility?

It is not preserving my `View` visibility. Is there a way to preserve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just noticed that the `View` visibility is treated as part of the constraints. Set it with

```
ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
set.setVisibility(checkIcon.getId(), INVISIBLE);
set.applyTo(container);
```

Comment: Gracias Eduardo, you're a lifesaver!